# Is swearing haram?

Tags: halal-haram

I don’t mean swearing AT someone. For example just saying “that’s f’ing great” or
“That’s absolutely f’ing abysmal”. Other questions I saw like this didn’t have ample evidence or didn’t answer rhe questions corrdctly.

Answer (score 1):

If we Muslims are told not to curse towards someone in the Qur’an, we’re definitely not allowed to curse in general, even if it’s for praise, exclamation, exaggeration, emphasis, etc.

Picture this: we all know we’re going to die. The angel of death could come to us at any given moment regardless if we’re healthy, young, and full of energy. The angel will come. Who’s to say you won’t die the moment you say that swear word? While yes it’s a very, very slim and rare chance you’ll actually die upon saying that word, but who knows? It’ll lead you to a habit of swearing a lot more frequently, to the point you’ll be swearing towards others as a joke or even angrily.

We Muslims shouldn’t be saying these filthy words because this is the same mouth that utters Allah’s name, Prophet Muhammad’s (saws) name, and the Quran. We shouldn’t fill it with dirt by saying such obscene and fowl language except by the remembrance of Allah. On the day of judgement, your tongue/mouth will testify against you for whatever you’ve said with the blessing Allah has bestowed upon you.

Has the Prophet ever slandered? Of course not. He encouraged us to speak good or remain silent. Don’t use fowl language even as a joke. Instead, spread peace with good words. Remember that you are an example towards the non Muslims. They’ll notice that as a Muslim you speak nothing but good, no slandering.

A side note, I also feel that swearing imitates the Kuffar which Prophet Muhammad (saws) explicitly states not to do.

Allah also says that when you want to exclaim praise like you’ve listed above in your example, instead of saying stuff like, “hell yeah!” Or “f*ck yeah!” Exclaim, “Alhamdulilah!” Or “Subhanallah!” Praise Allah for the good that happened to you.

In essence, it definitely is haram.

Answer (score -2):

swearing is a haram and you should try to stop inshAllah